# Testlink and Selenium 2

Tags: selenium, automation, testcase, bamboo

I am trying to generate test cases from a set of Selenium 2 test scripts that are formatted in a way that can TestLink can import.

Essentially I just have a ton of Selenium Test methods that generate reports in bamboo and i want a way to make TestLink eat those up so we dont have to manually enter all the test cases.

Has anybody tried anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have figured out something by now. However, there is no straight-forward way of doing this. Depending on what language your selenium 2 test cases are written in is going to determine what tools you use.

If it was me (and I use PHP implementation), I would most likely build a class that can be dropped in the place of the Webdriver object. For each Selenium command I would make it build a string instead of a sending a network call to Selenium server. With that said, I would probably translate it into [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin). At the end of the test, I would use [Testlink's API](http://teamst.org/_tldoc/1.8/phpdoc_api/TestlinkAPI/TestlinkXMLRPCServer.html) to create the test cases. I would probably do this part in [java](http://code.google.com/p/testlink-api-java-client/source/browse/?r=6#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftestlink-api-java-client%2Fsrc%2Ftestlink%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Fclient) for reuse later. I would then use PHPUnit's ability to export logs as JUnit, load them up, and then send them over to testlink using the same java client.

Lots of dev time...